# Was in the literature the function $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{N_n^s}$, where $N_n$ is the $n$th primorial number?

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, reference-request, analytic-continuation, primorial

I am curious to know if this function was in the literature, and mainly if it is possible define an analytic extension out of $\Re s>0$.

Let $N_n$ the $n$th primorial number, and $s=\sigma+it$ the complex variable. Then it is easy, using absolute convergence, to know that

$$\rho(s)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{N_n^s}\tag{1}$$
is analytic for $\Re s>0$ since converges absolutely for $\sigma>0$. One knows that has a pole at $s=0$. Also if $s=k+i\cdot0$ is a negative integer our series diverges.

I call $(1)$ the *Primorial zeta function*. But I don't know if the surname *zeta* is suitable.

> **Question.** Was in the literature our function $(1)$? Do you think that is it possible to define an analytic continuation, out of our pole $s=0$, to a small  strip at the left of the origin? If $(1)$ was in the literature, please refer the literature answering this question as a reference request, then I am going to search and read those statements. **Many thanks.**

I searched in Google *pseudo z functions, primorials*.

I know that if one can to find, for example, an integral representation for a function that extends the domain of definition of our complex function, then one can define an analytic extension from it.

Comment: Upvoted this one.

Comment: Many thanks @mick you are generous.

Comment: Im pretty sure this has a contour integral representation. But i have no proof. If the integral is not valid or diverges at crucial places, this might not be easy to make it analyticly continued. This reminds me of the prime zeta function. Maybe Google that ?

Comment: Yes, I tried find the function searching the prime zeta function, and the Wikipedia and MathWorld articles for primorials @mick

Comment: Where are the zero's I wonder ...

Comment: There is no mathematical question here. Analytic continuation isn't magic. Is there a chapter about this series in analytic-number-theory books ? By the way, what is its abscissa of convergence ? What is the one and only one method to continue analytically a Dirichlet series with non-negative coefficients ? @mick

Comment: @reuns I was wrong yesterday in some of my ideas about this series. I know how to prove that the abscissa of absolute convergence is $\sigma=0$ thus our series diverges at the left of such abscissa. I think that the method should be subtract the singulatity, or find an integral representation and study it.